# Java draw 3d points to 2d system using 3d projection

Tags: java, swing, 3d, 2d, projection

I have tried to follow the Wikipedia page on 3d projection to draw my own 3d line using java and AWT with Swing. 
The output file that is created as a result of the rendering doesn't contain anything.
What have I done wrong?
Why isn't this producing an image file that has points on it? 
Are my formulas off? 
I was following this Wikipedia page as my reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection

I have a set of points which are generated using a loop. 
I then calculate the position of the 3d coordinate to 2d without using matrices, like one of the suggested method in the link.

Have I miss-interpreted something or not implemented something?
Any help and feedback are welcome.

I known nothing is drawn to the window. That isn't a priority at the moment. The priority it's getting the algorithms to work.

```
public class Window {
JFrame f = new JFrame();

public Window() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    render();
    f.add(p);
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Window w = new Window();
}

void render() {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Vector3 point = new Vector3(1 + i, 2, 1 + i);
        int x = calculateBX(point, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        int y = calculateBY(point, new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
    }

    try {
        File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

double calculatDX(Vector3 v, Vector3 camera) {
    double cx = Math.cos(0);
    double cy = Math.cos(0);
    double cz = Math.cos(0);

    double sx = Math.sin(0);
    double sy = Math.sin(0);
    double sz = Math.sin(0);

    int x = v.getX() - camera.getX();
    int y = v.getY() - camera.getY();
    int z = v.getZ() - camera.getZ();

    double dx = cy * ((sz) * (y) + (cz) * (x)) - (sy) * (z);
    return dx;
}

double calculatDY(Vector3 v, Vector3 camera) {
    double cx = Math.cos(0);
    double cy = Math.cos(0);
    double cz = Math.cos(0);

    double sx = Math.sin(0);
    double sy = Math.sin(0);
    double sz = Math.sin(0);

    int x = v.getX() - camera.getX();
    int y = v.getY() - camera.getY();
    int z = v.getZ() - camera.getZ();

    double dy = sx * ((cy) * (z) + (sy) * ((sz) * (y) + (cz) * (x))) + (cx) * (cz * (y) - sz * x);
    return dy;
}

double calculatDZ(Vector3 v, Vector3 camera) {
    double cx = Math.cos(0);
    double cy = Math.cos(0);
    double cz = Math.cos(0);

    double sx = Math.sin(0);
    double sy = Math.sin(0);
    double sz = Math.sin(0);

    int x = v.getX() - camera.getX();
    int y = v.getY() - camera.getY();
    int z = v.getZ() - camera.getZ();

    double dz = cx * ((cy) * (z) + (sy) * ((sz) * (y) + (cz) * (x))) - (sx) * (cz * (y) - sz * x);
    return dz;
}

int calculateBX(Vector3 v, Vector3 camera) {
    int ez = camera.getZ();
    int ex = camera.getX();
    double dz = calculatDZ(v, camera);
    double dx = calculatDX(v, camera);

    return (int) ((ez / dz) * dx) - ex;
}

int calculateBY(Vector3 v, Vector3 camera) {
    int ez = camera.getZ();
    int ey = camera.getY();
    double dz = calculatDZ(v, camera);
    double dy = calculatDY(v, camera);

    return (int) ((ez / dz) * dy) - ey;
}
}
```

Vector Class

```
public class Vector3 {
private int x, y, z;

public Vector3(int x, int y, int z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getZ() {
    return z;
}
}
```

Comment: You rendered an image.  You wrote that image to a file.  That doesn’t display it on the screen.  Perhaps you meant to create an ImageIcon from your image, create a JLabel that uses that ImageIcon, and add that JLabel to your JPanel?

Comment: Change `File outputfile = new File("saved.png"); ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);` to `File outputfile = new File("saved.png"); ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile); Dektop.getDesktop().open(outputfile);` & report back. Unless there is a stack trace from that code, the image should be written properly.

Comment: General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) Note that `Window` is a poor name, given `java.awt.Window` exists.

Comment: The problem I have isn't with displaying the photo. I look at the file created in an editor for that. my problem is that the algorithms for converting the points from 3D to 2D isn't working.

Comment: Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: `g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);` draws a line with zero length—that is, it draws nothing.  If you want a single pixel at (x,y), try something like `g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);`.